# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_'

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

The Grad sub object becomes "None" if expand the expression. Not sure why? Can somebody give some clue. 
If expand the w.grand.zero_() throw error as "**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_'**"

Thanks,
Ganesh

```
import torch

x = torch.randint(size = (1,2), high = 10)
w = torch.Tensor([16,-14])
b = 36

y = w * x + b

epoch = 20
learning_rate = 0.01

w1 = torch.rand(size= (1,2), requires_grad= True)
b1 = torch.ones(size = [1], requires_grad= True)

for i in range(epoch):
    y1 = w1 * x + b1

    loss = torch.sum((y1-y)**2)

    loss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        #w1 = w1 - learning_rate * w1.grad  //Not Working : w1.grad becomes "None" not sure how ;(
        #b1 = b1 - learning_rate * b1.grad  

        w1 -= (learning_rate * w1.grad)  // Working code.
        b1 -= (learning_rate * b1.grad)

        w1.grad.zero_()
        b1.grad.zero_()

    print("B ", b1)  
    print("W ", w1)
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You should ask yourself why you have a `NoneType` (i.e. value `None`) instead of what your code expected. Also, ask yourself why your code expects that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I just pasted whole code so that anyone can copy and paste to execute for see more insights.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that in your working code you are modifying existing variable which has `grad` attribute, while in the `non-working` case you are creating a new variable.

As new `w1`/`b1` variable is created it has no gradient attribute as you didn't call `backward()` on it, but on the "original" variable.

First, let's check whether that's really the case:

```
print(id(w1)) # Some id returned here
w1 = w1 - learning_rate * w1.grad

# In case below w1 address doesn't change
# w1 -= learning_rate * w1.grad 

print(id(w1)) # Another id here
```

Now, you could copy it in-place and not brake it, but there is no point to do so and your working case is much clearer, but for posterity's sake:

```
w1.copy_(w1 - learning_rate * w1.grad)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is updating the parameters w and b using gradient descent. In the first line, w.grad is the gradient of the loss function with respect to the parameter w and lr is the learning rate, a scalar value that determines the step size in the direction of the gradient.

The second line, b = b - b.grad * lr is updating the parameter b in the same way, by subtracting the gradient of the loss with respect to b multiplied by the learning rate.

However, the second line is incorrect, it should be b -= b.grad * lr instead of b = b - b.grad * lr

Using b = b - b.grad * lr would cause the parameter b to be re-assigned to the new value, but the original b would not be updated, therefore, the value of b would be None.

On the other hand, using b -= b.grad * lr will update the value of b in place, so the original b will be updated and its value will not be None.